# How to filter GWT requestFactory results?

Tags: gwt, filter, filtering, requestfactory

I have a question about how to do data filtering with RequestFactory in GWT. I am currently working on an application which is backed by a MySQL database. My persistence layer is based on JPA/Hibernate. I am using RequestFactory to query my database for all my listing-related operations.

So for example, I have a Person object : In my PersonRequestContext I have a method which allows me to list persons. The method signature is :

```
Request<List<PersonProxy>> listPersons(Integer firstResult, Integer maxResults);
```

As you may have guessed, the corresponding query is something like this :

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p ORDER BY p.id").setFirstResult(firstResult).setMaxResults(maxResults).getResultList();
```

Now, **I would like to filter the result based on table columns**. So I wanted to use some kind of Filter class abstraction to solve it. The problem is that as we all know, it's not possible to pass non-primitive objects in to the requestFactory method.

Have you ever experienced this kind of thing ? And how did you deal with it to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assertion that only primitive types can be passed to a Request method is incorrect.  See the documentation on [transportable types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#transportable).  You can create a `ValueProxy` hierarchy to model your filters.

Comment: Oh I see, I was totally wrong. Thanks a lot for correcting me. I will try to solve it with your suggestion ...

again thanks a lot,

Comment: Ok, so here is what I have tried to do : I have created an object (let's say A) on the server-side and AProxy which extends ValueProxy on the client side. I just want to **Send a value pair** on the server side (it seems so simple and I am probably stupid).
just have an AProxy populate its field and send it to the server ...
How can I create an AProxy object on the client side ? And how can I annotate the RequestContext with the @service given the fact that it will not have any service-related feature  (I mean no db queries or stg like that to achieve) ?

thanks a lot